# Firebase Messaging - Null check operator used on a null value?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

import '../../export.dart';

class FirebaseNotificationManager {
  FirebaseNotificationManager._privateConstructor();

  static final FirebaseNotificationManager _instance = FirebaseNotificationManager._privateConstructor();

  factory FirebaseNotificationManager() {
    return _instance;
  }

  init() async {
    // add firebase notification permission
    FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: true,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );
    if (await Permission.notification.request().isGranted) {
      try {
        // Either the permission was already granted before or the user just granted it.
        FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_messageHandler);
        _firebaseMessagingListener();
        String? deviceToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
        logger.i(deviceToken);
      } catch (e) {
        logger.i(e);
      }
    }
  }

  /// must call it from view after getContext is initialized to show dialog message
  checkAndroid() async {
    if (!(await Permission.notification.request().isGranted) && GetPlatform.isAndroid) {
      showOptionsDialog(
          text: 'إذا كنت ترغب في تلقي الاشعارات ،برجاء اعطاء إذن الاشعارات في الإعدادات وإعادة تشغيل التطبيق',
          yesFunction: (context) async {
            openAppSettings();
          });
    }
  }

  // execute if app in background
  Future<void> _messageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    // Data notificationMessage = Data.fromJson(message.data);
    log('notification from background : ${message.toMap()}');
  }

// execute if app in foreground
  void _firebaseMessagingListener() {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      logger.i('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
      logger.i('Message data: ${message.data}');

      if (message.notification != null) {
        logger.i('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification!.toMap()}');
        logger.i('Message also contained a notification: ${message.toMap()}');
        // that means new message

        try {
          Get.snackbar(message.notification!.title.toString(), message.notification!.body.toString(),
              duration: Duration(seconds: 6),
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(Get.context!).cardColor,
              barBlur: 10,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8));
        } catch (e) {
          logger.i(e);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, you need to put the onBackgroundMessage function outside of a class, at the top of your file as a top-level function. See Firebase messaging example for implementation.

[source](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8864)

file became:

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

import '../../export.dart';

init() async {
  // add firebase notification permission
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: true,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );
  if (await Permission.notification.request().isGranted) {
    try {
      // Either the permission was already granted before or the user just granted it.
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_messageHandler);
      _firebaseMessagingListener();
      String? deviceToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
      logger.i(deviceToken);
    } catch (e) {
      logger.i(e);
    }
  }
}

/// must call it from view after getContext is initialized to show dialog message
checkAndroid() async {
  if (!(await Permission.notification.request().isGranted) && GetPlatform.isAndroid) {
    showOptionsDialog(
        text: 'إذا كنت ترغب في تلقي الاشعارات ،برجاء اعطاء إذن الاشعارات في الإعدادات وإعادة تشغيل التطبيق',
        yesFunction: (context) async {
          openAppSettings();
        });
  }
}

// execute if app in background
Future<void> _messageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // Data notificationMessage = Data.fromJson(message.data);
  log('notification from background : ${message.toMap()}');
}

// execute if app in foreground
void _firebaseMessagingListener() {
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    logger.i('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
    logger.i('Message data: ${message.data}');

    if (message.notification != null) {
      logger.i('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification!.toMap()}');
      logger.i('Message also contained a notification: ${message.toMap()}');
      // that means new message

      try {
        Get.snackbar(message.notification!.title.toString(), message.notification!.body.toString(),
            duration: Duration(seconds: 6),
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(Get.context!).cardColor,
            barBlur: 10,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8));
      } catch (e) {
        logger.i(e);
      }
    }
  });
}
```